# response.css html on Scrapy

Tags: html, scrapy, tripadvisor

I'm trying to extract the html link from the "website" here
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g982688-d1140717-Reviews-Strandkanten-Karlskoga_Orebro_County.html
https://monosnap.com/file/agSNP29XoLDlG4HZtntaaifAtFPzcH
i tried response.css('a.dOGcA::attr(href)').extract()
but it is giving a blank response
what am i doing wrong?
thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you are going to scrape is loaded dynamically. If you make disabled javascript then you will see that the  url/href goes disappeared from the html Dom that's why I use `SeleniumRequest` with scrapy   and getting the desired output.

Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'link'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g982688-d1140717-Reviews-Strandkanten-Karlskoga_Orebro_County.html'
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url=url,
            wait_time=3,
            callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        
        yield {'Link':response.xpath('//a[@class="dOGcA Ci Wc _S C fhGHT"]/@href').get()}
       

    def spider_closed(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

Output:

```
2021-10-24 01:25:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g982688-d1140717-Reviews-Strandkanten-Karlskoga_Orebro_County.html>
{'Link': 'http://www.strandkanten.nu'}
```